# When using jupyterlab in anaconda for python programming, how can I display vertical grid lines in the cell?

Tags: python-3.x, view, jupyter-lab

When programming in python, the number of spaces is very important. When there are many lines of code, I can't see how many spaces are empty. Is there a way to make the cell display vertical grid lines?
I searched on Google and chatgpt, but couldn't find a good solution.
Can you help me find a solution, thank you all.